# Google Fusion Styles api, last style applied to all

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

So I'm trying to apply styles according to contents of a string in a certain column, at the moment I'm just testing for one particular string.

```
function makeMap(lat, lng, zoom) {
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googft-mapCanvas'), {
      center: myLatLng,
      zoom: zoom,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
      map: map,
      heatmap: { enabled: false },
      query: {
        select: "col5",
        from: "1Qrjmw1bt5n__AQhdCbiShbMCVS8FqySXx8Jie4A",
        where: "month = 2013-05 || month = 2013-06"
      },
      styles: [
        { markerOptions: { iconName: 'small_yellow' }},
        {
            where: "'Last outcome category' = 'No further action at this time'",
            markerOptions: { iconName: 'small_red' }
        }
      ],
      options: {
        templateId: 2
      }
    });

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatLng,
          map: map,
          title:"You are here!"
      });

 }
```

What this seems to be doing at the moment is applying the last style to everything, so in this case everything is the red marker but if I switch it around everything will be the yellow marker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The where clause in the FusionTableLayer query is invalid

```
where: "month = 2013-05 || month = 2013-06"
```

(There is no 'or' (||) operator in FusionTables)  It seems to be causing the styles not to be processed correctly.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTables_StyleA.html)